# Javascript object inheritance not showing expected result

Tags: javascript, oop

I used to think that both assignments `a = "foo"` and `a = new String('foo')` are the same things. But with the former declaration, `console.log(a instanceof Object)` or `console.log(a instanceof String)` returns `false`, while it returns the expected `true` for the latter.

This seems weird for two reasons. Firstly, even with the normal declaration `a = 'foo'`, all string methods work on it, suggesting that it has inherited from `String` object. And secondly, `a.constructor` returns `String`.

Can anybody explain what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"foo"` is a primitive literal.

But `new String("foo")` is an instance of the class String.

You can call methods on the primitive value because

> JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so
>   that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.  In contexts where a method is to be invoked on a primitive string or a property lookup occurs, JavaScript will automatically wrap the string primitive and call the method or perform the property lookup.

(from [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String))

Comment: Can you please explain what is meant by primitive value? And how then, does it have `constructor` property?

Comment: `JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects`. Then, it should return `true` for `console.log(a instanceof String)`, right?

Comment: Primitive value (which can also be boolean or numbers) are simply lighter values and not instances. But the js engine makes it possible to call methods by promoting them when needed. But only when needed (that is when you need to call a method, not when you call instanceof).

Comment: This provides a pretty good explanation of the primitive vs object question: http://skypoetsworld.blogspot.com/2007/11/javascript-string-primitive-or-object.html

the main punchline though is: "The difference between a primitive and a String object is when you're adding functionality to a String. You can't do it to primitives.

So, if you wanted to add a function to reverse the characters in a string, you'd do something like this by adding it to the String object's prototype property --"

Comment: Oh, I did not know that! Thanks! So, for both property lookup and constructor finding, it wraps up the primitive in the corresponding object?

Comment: Yes, that's what's is done. And it's well done enough so you don't have to think about it too much. Except if you're using `===`...

Comment: "you don't have to think about it too much." That is true if you don't use `String` objects. In fact, the reason *why* you should not use `String` objects at all is because if you do, you *will* have to think about it.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Yes. I meant that the occasional promotion of a string to a String wasn't generally a problem. But if you start with Strings instead of strings, then you'll have to think.